# module "OpenGLUnderQML" is not installed

Tags: package-management, qt

Here's what my main.qml file does to cause this error:

```
import OpenGLUnderQML 1.0
```

What should I install on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [search on packages.ubuntu.com for *OpenGLUnderQML*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=OpenGLUnderQML) gives the following package name - `qtdeclarative5-examples`. If you install it you will get all needed dependencies such as Qt5 and Qt Quick.

So you need to install this package and qt5 development tools:

```
sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-examples qtdeclarative5-dev qt5-default
```

and if you want you can install html-help with

```
sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-doc-html
```

Also note, that you can use any of examples located in */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/quick* (including yours OpenGLUnderQML one -  */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/quick/scenegraph/openglunderqml/openglunderqml*).

You can compile OpenGLUnderQML and test it with commands below:

```
cp -ar /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/quick/scenegraph/openglunderqml ~/
cd ~/openglunderqml
qmake
make
./openglunderqml
```

[image: openglunderqml on 18.04 LTS]